# Tor auto-exits when opened - Mac

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

When ever I open Tor on my mac, 10.9.5 version, and when ever I open Tor it crashes when establishing network contact. This happens on what ever network I use. I've tried to reinstall it but the problem's still there.

[image: Network settings]

Comment: Can you "Copy Tor Log to Clipboard" and insert the output into your question?

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have enough rep to comment but hopefully this is helpful.)

Make sure you check your Tor config as a setting you recently changed might cause the Tor Engine to not start. I had the same problem when I forgot the `file` in the `Log notice file tor.log` line in my config. If you are not sure what happened you can always re-download the latest Tor (Browser) and reinstall it.